# How to add a custom text for order confirmation email template woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hi i would like to add a custom text in order confirmation email template . Currently i am not using woo commerce tax option, But i would like to mention my product has 25 % including vat in email template . That custom text need to show only in order confirmation email template near Order total : Total:   348.00 DKK ( Including tax 25% ) .

Comment: Have you override the woo-commerce template?

Comment: There's a simple plugin for this http://wp-html-mail.com/woocommerce-custom-email-content/

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom text or html using this action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

  function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
   if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
     echo 'Custom HTml OR Custom Text';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your child theme folder.

Find woccomerce > emails

from here you can edit your email template.

Refer [this link](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) this will might be helpful

Comment: Hi Mitual I did't override my Email template , and will try with Anam shah comment.